# SQLite Guide to Monotouch Development

Tags: sqlite, orm, xamarin.ios

Hi do you know any resource wherein they have a complete guide on how to use SQLite on Monotouch (the one with ORM functions)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this? https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Once you read that, you might find https://github.com/jstedfast/MonoTouch.SQLite useful for pulling data from an sqlite db into a UITableViewController.

Comment: yeah but sqlite-net on github didn't provide step by step guide on how to use it. do you have one?

Comment: What step-by-step directions do you need that the sqlite-net docs don't already provide?